# observer methods never used

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm still trying to figure out observers in RxJava. I have a Retrofit client, a utility methods and a class that manages a data syncing feature. When I attempt to observe my observables I am not seeing any indication that the observer is subscribed.

My Utility method

```
public static Single<Response<SyncResponse>> getSyncData() {

    Single response = FestApiClient.getInstance().postSyncData()
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    return response;
}
```

My retorfit client

```
public Single<Response<SyncResponse>> postSyncData() {

    Single response = mFestApiClientService.postEventSyncList("my endpoint");
    return response;

}
```

And my data syncing manager

```
Disposable syncDisposable = ScheduleUtils.getSyncData().subscribe(syncResponse -> {


        if (syncResponse.isSuccessful()){
            Log.d(TAG, "Successfully posted events!");

            addEventsFromSync(syncResponse.body());
            mSyncDialog.dismiss();

        } else {
            getFailureMessage(syncResponse.body());
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed posting events");


        }
    }, throwable -> {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed posting events");

    });
    mCompositeDisposable.add(syncDisposable);
```

I thought that the syncResponse.onFailure and onSuccess methods would be hit, but i never see the log messages or hit break points. I'd appreciate if you let me know if you see anything smelly. thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `mCompositeDisposable.isDisposed()` before that `add`?

Comment: ```CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();```

Comment: I meant add `System.out.println(mCompositeDisposable.isDisposed());` before `mCompositeDisposable.add(syncDisposable);` and tell us what it prints to the console.

Comment: My bad. im getting ```mCompositeDisposable: false``` in my logcat

Comment: In that case, start adding doOnNext/doOnSuccess calls at various places to see where events stop. You can also add doOnSubscribe/doOnDispose calls as well.

Comment: any luck on solving this @DanSchneider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are observing on the wrong thread. Switch AndroidSchedulers so that it is on the main thread.

```
public static Single<Response<SyncResponse>> getSyncData() {

     Single response = FestApiClient.getInstance().postSyncData()
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
             .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
     return response;
}
```